# Test against static library gets symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, testing, bazel

I use Bazel to build my project which has a dependency like that

```
main <- libA <- libB
```

libA is a regular header and src file, libB is a static library with its headers

when I use Bazel build it works fine. but now I create a cc_test for libB and it shows me this error:

```
/_solib_k8/libB.so: symbol lookup error
```

I can't provide the source code but can you please think of any reason why that could happen

I tried to build and it works fine and Bazel test is not working.

Comment: Fyi this symbols is found in libB.o

Comment: Did you add `libB` as a dependency to your test? E.g. `cc_test(name = libB_test, deps = ":libB", srcs = ...)`? Can you provide a minimal failing example?

Comment: Yes sure, The issue with linkstatic not set to 1. which i thought not necessary for cc_test

Answer (score 0):

For static library to be linked with your cc_* you have to put this:

```
linkstatic = 1,
```